# Ruby: In a n-element array, which is faster: array[-1] or array[n-1]?

Tags: ruby, arrays

If `array = [1, 2, 3]`, then theoretically speaking, is there a difference in speed between calling `array[-1]` and `array[2]`?

(And in general terms, for any array where `array.length == n`, is there a difference between calling `array[-1]` and `array[n-1]`?)

Comment: "No". The difference *where (if)* the 'length - 1' is done and is inconsequential to any actual performance. Follow the 97/3 rule.

Comment: @user2864740 Can you explain what you mean by the 97/3 rule?

Comment: ["We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)  - Knuth/Hoare. Both the 97 *and* 3 components are important; but this is not, in any conceivable manner, the 3. (I avoid using just the middle part of the quote as it is a hyperbole and misses the important context.)

Comment: Thanks for the article link.

Comment: @user2864740: Thanks for keeping the context. That quote is so often misrepresented.

Comment: No, there is no difference that will be relevant at all in any real-world application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not an expert, so benchmarked to test which one is faster,

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'bigdecimal/math'

array = (1..10000).to_a

puts Benchmark.measure { puts array[-1] }
#=> 0.000030

puts Benchmark.measure { puts array[10000-1] }
#=> 0.000031
```

I think the difference is negligible.

Comment: Note: This uber-micro benchmark does *not* imply `a[-1]` is "faster" or even that there is a measurable difference, but it does indicate that "it doesn't matter".

Comment: @user2864740, yes it doesn't matter.

Comment: Putting `puts` inside the block distorts the results, and performing a single calculation for each is not sufficient.  I changed your benchmarks to `{ 1_000_000.times { a = array[-1] } }` and `{ 1_000_000.times { a = array[10000-1] } } `, did 10 runs and found found that the first was faster by an average of 10.5%, but the percentages by with the first was faster varied quite a bit, as shown in the following (sorted, with values rounded) array:  `[45, 37, 8, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 0, -2]`.

Comment: It's worth noting that getting `n` might be the slow part here, so `array[array.length-1]` vs. `array[-1]` is a more fair comparison.

Comment: @tadman, I reran the benchmarks with `{ 1_000_000.times { array[-1] } }` and `{ 1_000_000.times { array[10000-1] } }`. This time the first was on average 4.3% faster. The percentage differences were as follows: `[25, 13, 6, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, -2, -13]`.  Eliminating the assignment `a = ` reduced solution times by about 5% (only).  The two sets of results don't seem consistent, but I expect that's due to my relatively small sample size (of 10).

Answer (score 1):

We should measure! I'm going to hypothesize that [-1] and `#last` will be slightly faster than `[len - 1]` due to having one less method call.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

arr = (1..100).to_a

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("last") { arr.last }
  x.report("-1") { arr[-1] }
  x.report("len - 1") { arr[arr.length - 1] }
end
```

Results:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby bench.rb

Calculating -------------------------------------
                last    127496 i/100ms
                  -1    133726 i/100ms
             len - 1    127050 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
                last  6528395.1 (±0.4%) i/s -   32638976 in   4.999622s
                  -1  7802109.3 (±1.7%) i/s -   39047992 in   5.006745s
             len - 1  7046531.5 (±0.3%) i/s -   35319900 in   5.012415s

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby bench.rb

Calculating -------------------------------------
                last    130228 i/100ms
                  -1    129587 i/100ms
             len - 1    126966 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
                last  6787424.0 (±0.2%) i/s -   33989508 in   5.007732s
                  -1  7915058.4 (±0.6%) i/s -   39653622 in   5.010079s
             len - 1  7126295.0 (±0.5%) i/s -   35677446 in   5.006563s


$ ruby -v
jruby 1.7.18 (1.9.3p551) 2014-12-22 625381c on
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_25-b18 +jit [linux-amd64]
$ ruby bench.rb

Calculating -------------------------------------
                last   212.085k i/100ms
                  -1   226.292k i/100ms
             len - 1   226.245k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
                last     13.935M (± 4.4%) i/s -     69.352M
                  -1     13.696M (± 5.1%) i/s -     68.340M
             len - 1     11.732M (± 3.2%) i/s -     58.597M
```

-1 is very slightly faster under ruby 2.0.0 and 2.1.1, `#last` is fastest under JRuby (which is itself almost 2x faster than MRI, probably because of that delicious JIT).

In all cases, it runs *really fast* and it's probably one of the last things you should be trying to optimize.